# The Raptor - Jurassic Park

Tags: raptor, dinosaur, jurassic-park

Hey all,

Im interested in recreating a few Raptor calls - Heavily influenced by Jurassic Park.

Take a listen to these particular ones:

- 0:18 - laugh like - during "otherwise we would be dead already"
- 0:21 - short and bursty
- 1:17 - seal like - hornish

http://youtu.be/Du95opzY8qg?hd=1

Brainstorming myself, it sounds like the first is a combination of time-shifted chickens and roosters as base layers.

Second one sounds more "airy" version of the first sound. A longer form of 1 laugh, yet it has a distinct air to it - almost in the background of the sound is a far off air compressor soaked and blurred in reverb to be mixed in with the chicken.

And the third sound comes the obvious seal/walrus approach. But what gets me is the distorted characteristic of the beginning. I almost want to say its the same layer duplicated and bit crushed and mixed in just slightly.

What do you all think?

- C3

Comment: I've recorded some Grey Crowned Cranes at a local Zoo they were making similar calls like at 1:17 but just higher pitched.

Comment: Hmm. Spielberg's IMDB shows a Jurassic Park IV in the making... Fancy that!

Comment: awesome! cant wait for that

Answer (score 3):

Why not get the answer from the man himself. Gary Rydstrom goes into detail [here](http://www.mpse.org/education/bigmovierydstrom.html).

Comment: @JustinPearson Very good! Thanks so much for posting this! Solid read for sure.

Answer (score 1):

From Justins post above, here are some excerpts from Gary's interview.

"I had a neighbor who had a de-barked dog. I didn't de-bark the dog myself, but it made this amazing slicing/breathing sound that I used for the raptor."

"That became raptor breathing, when the raptor shows up and looks in the window of the kitchen and snorts, that's just an angry horse."

"So in the case of the raptor, there was no one animal sound that made the sound of the raptor vocals, it really was made up of many, and they were chosen for each of their… But it is orchestrating. It's taking sounds... the strongest example of taking two sounds of different frequencies and putting them together are the walrus sound, which is a very low WRRR, which is cut for the raptor attack scream; and then the dolphin scream which we recorded underwater with a hydrophone of a dolphin in heat, it turned out. A dolphin that made this high-pitched scream. Neither one was right by itself, but if you blend them together you get this high-pitched scream blended with a low walrus -- then together they made the scream of the raptor, so two animals blended into what sounded like a third."

Anyone got a de-barked dog? Hahahaha.

Still want peoples ideas on these particular 3 to try out. Ill me making them within the next day - so Ill post how it goes!

Thanks!

Comment: I think Chris Boyes was the sound designer on Jurassic Park III, he probably did it differently if that's the sound your going for, just so you know.

Comment: @StephenSaldanha The game director specifically picked out the first Jurassic Park, so I've been looking into the older videos. Good to know though, thanks!